# Manually Paging in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, paging, scrollview

I have a scrollview with lets say ten subviews in it. All are shown at the same time. I want to page between each subview.

One idea is to set the frame size equal to a single subview and turn the paging on. But then it will receive the touch only within that frame. I want the user should be able to scroll it from any where in that scrollview.

For Example:

| sub1    sub2     sub3    sub4    sub5    sub6    sub7    sub8    sub9    sub10 |

I want the user to scroll it from any where in this scrollview, and page between these subviews.

Any Idea?

Comment: It might just be me, but I really don't understand this. Why would you want to page between subviews if they're all visible already?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795).

Answer (score 0):

make a frame that is the size of the subviews (`frame`) and then set these:

```
scrollview.pagingEnables = YES;
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*numberofsubviews,  frame.size.height);
```

The UIScrollView should handle everything else from there on out.

The link that Toro sent you will help a great deal, I wouldn't avoid that if I were you

This link will help as well [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)